# Create file with certain specifications from vector graphic/PDF

Tags: gimp, inkscape, pdf, dpi, measurement

I've been asked to create a PDF or TIF file with 300 dpi, featuring a logo in grayscale, measuring 1 inch (25.4 mm) width max and 0.5 inch (12.7 mm) in height max.

I'm by no means an expert, but I've done a couple of basic things in editing software like GIMP and Inkscape.

The logo that is supposed to be in the file is available as a PDF file (colored) and as an SVG graphic, I once extracted from the PDF with Inkscape.

I know how to create the PDF/TIF and make a grayscale of the logo, but other requirements are a bit of a mystery to me.

How do I make sure the logo is of a certain size in inch/mm and how do I define the DPI of the document?

Comment: 300dpi, 1x 0.5"..... make a file 300 x 150px and you're good.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft could you elaborate that a bit? How do I calculate the inch to pixel?

Comment: ok - 300 dpi (dots per inch) i.e 300 pixels per inch - therefore 1 inch width = 300 pixels, 0.5 height is 150.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft Can I convert DPI to PPI just like that? I thought that makes a difference for the printing process.

Comment: Generally yes - the print RIP will take care of the rest.

Comment: I was once young and naive and thought that when a person gives you out specifications that they know what they want. Well, on one of my first jobs i  was given 6 requirements out of which exactly 0 were what they wanted. They literally didn't want the file format they specified, they didn't want it done in the software they specified, they dint want it in the time frame they specified and so on... Failure to know this is a failure on you, unfortunately. Just because somebody specifies XXX does not mean anything until you have had a discussion of what the requirements are for.

Comment: On DPI: Most of the time yes, most of the time whan people say DPI they are talking about PPI (as in they meant to say PPI but dont know they should be talking about PPI). But if your seeing a printer specification then your PPI should be 1.8-2.2* LPI. If somebody says 300 DPI they just mean print ready, and do not actually know any better. Which is why I am saying that the specification may not hold water!

Comment: ^^Additionally home printers often go to 1400+ dpi, but that is actual dots for gradation/blending purposes, the printer isnt actually printing a 1400 ppi image natively...

Answer (score 3):

A vector file has no need to define the ppi, except in the case you are using some kind of rasterized effects, for example shadows in some programs are raster (pixel based)

Vector files will give you the option to work directly on phisical units, so you simply choose the unit and that is it.

Regarding a TIF file, that is raster, so you simply export your vector file.

300ppi mean that you have 300 pixels on one inch. If the logo measures 1 inch it measures 300px. That is what 300 pixels per inch mean.

On the short side, half inch it is half the 300px. 150px.

Answer (score 0):

With Shift-Ctrl-D you enter the settings of your document. There you may set  calculated values from Rafael et.al. and resize your image to the document size.

With Shift-Ctrl-E you get the file export dialog, where you simply set the DPI to 300.